# AbstractMethodError thrown when creating a Clob object in Java oracle procedure

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I'm developing a Java PLSQL procedure that must instanciate a CLOB object. In order to instanciate that Clob object I must use a connection object. Based on [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chone.htm#JJDEV01000), I can get the current connection using java.sql.DriverManager however when I execute the following code an AbstractMethodError error is thrown

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");
Clob clob = conn.createClob();
```

I see a lot of posts talking about driver compatibility with Java runtime running the code but as I am working inside an Oracle DB I suppose it should be compatible.

Oracle version: 11.2.0.4.0

My goal is to create a clob inside my java method and return it to my plsql code. How can I instanciate a Clob inside a java class stored inside an Oracle database ?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creation of the `CLOB`using `conn.createClob()` works for my fine in 12c. I suspect from your error message in 11 you'll have to use the `CLOB.createTemporary` method to create the CLOB (which works fine in 12c as well but is marked as *deprecated*).

Here an example

**Java class**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "CreateCLOB"
AS 
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;

/****** START PASTE JAVA CLASS HERE *****/
public class CreateCLOB{

  public static void ClobProc (Clob cl[]) throws SQLException
  {
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:default:connection:"); /* or use "jdbc:oracle:kprb:" */

    Clob clob =  CLOB.createTemporary(conn, false, oracle.sql.CLOB.DURATION_SESSION); /* this is deprecated in 12c */
                // conn.createClob(); /* works fine in 12.1.0.2.0 */
    clob.setString(1, "Test Data");
    cl[0] = clob;
  }
}
/
```

**Wrapper**

```
create or replace procedure MyClob (cl OUT Clob) 
  as language java
  name 'CreateCLOB.ClobProc(java.sql.Clob[])';
/
```

**Test**

```
declare
x Clob;

begin
  MyClob(x);
  dbms_output.put_line('created CLOB length = ' || dbms_lob.getlength(x));
end;
/

created CLOB length = 9
```

As mentioned I can't test it on version 11, but I suppose it will work.

```
select * from v$version;
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
```

Comment: I confirm it works as you expected on Oracle 11.2 ! Thanks ;-) Do you have any documentation explaining why we have to use CLOB.createTemporary ?

Comment: createClob is defined in interface java.sql.Connection. Interface  oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection in [11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html) do not inherit it. It is implemented starting with [12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html) - which explains the abstractMethod exception in 11g.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow these steps:

**1. On your computer you should have an Oracle jdbc driver** (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html)

**2. Load a driver**

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

**3. Get a connection**

```
Connection connection =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:SID","username","password");
```

UPDATE: If you work inside of Oracle DB, you can choose a type of driver (Server-Side Thin Driver or Server-Side Internal Driver) - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html

Comment: As I explained, I'm not on my computer but inside an Oracle DB. My code will be executed as an Oracle Java Procedure like described in https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm

Comment: I updated my answer, did you try to use these types of drivers?

Comment: I tried... If I can answer you point by point: 1. Yes I have an Oracle jdbc driver as I am directly inside the database. 2. I tried with and without the driver loading. I suppose Oracle load this for us automatically. 3. I get the connection with  `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");` that's how the oracle documentation explain we can get the current connection related to the procedure call. I think the issue is more a configuration of my Oracle Server than a java code issue.

Answer (score 0):

Even when you are not using the createClob() you may get this error when starting the application if you are using an older version of hibernate core library.

The errors is just thrown, but the application starts. If you are not worried about it you may leave it, but if you don't want to see an error during application startup then her is the fix.

Its a bug in the Spring boot 2.X - hibernate core 5.3.X combination. There are 2 solutions for the issue. I would suggest #1.

1. Upgrade all hibernate libraries to 5.4.X (my way)
2. Provide **spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true** in your application properties/ yml file.(If you really do not want to upgrade your hibernate core library).

I have got this when upgrading spring boot to 2.4 and using Teradata DB without any createClob().

If you still want to know how the error is being created, its well explained in https://alexpask.com/spring-boot-createclob-error/